# How to bind data from backend into frontend at select option angular 9

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am saving a number in backend which then I am trying through this number to show the selected object at select option at Angular.

So far it is only showing the list which I have declared in the TS with enums.
But my problem it is that I have saved in backend a number and then in HTML is not the selected value I wish.

Here is the stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fvvnga?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

The HTML it is like this.

```
<select #selectedValue name="selectedValue"
        id="selectedValue" [ngModel]="selectedValue"
        (ngModelChange)="assignCorporationToManage($event)" class="col-md-12 form-control-sm">
           <option *ngFor="let employment of employmentType"
                   [ngValue]="employment" [selected]="employment">
                {{employment.description | translate}}
           </option>
</select>
```

The **TS** looks like this.

```
  public employmentType = [
    {name: EmploymentType.EmployedFullTime, description: "employmentType.EmployedFullTime"},
    {name: EmploymentType.EmployedPartTime, description: "employmentType.EmployedPartTime"},
    {name: EmploymentType.Internship, description: "employmentType.Internship"},
    {name: EmploymentType.Owner, description: "employmentType.Owner"},
    {name: EmploymentType.BordMember, description: "employmentType.Boardmember"},
    {name: EmploymentType.Volunteer, description: "employmentType.Volunteer"},
  ];
```

Here is the `ngModelChange`

```
assignCorporationToManage(selectedValue) {
console.log(selectedValue); //Here it is returning me the number
}
```

This is the enum.

```
export enum EmploymentType {
  EmployedFullTime,
  EmployedPartTime,
  Internship,
  Owner,
  BordMember,
  Volunteer,
  SelfEmployed,
  Shareholder,
  Official,
  Recruiter,
  Freelancer,
  Partner
}
```

But I do have data which I read from backend.

```
companyUrl: "www.1234.de"
description: "test"
employmentType: 3
endDate: "2020-09-30"
name: "muster"
role: "IT Web Developer"
startDate: "2020-09-30"
```

And here as u can see the `employmentType` is 3 which means the `EmploymentType.Owner` is selected.

But in HTML I am not able to show which is selected from employment type.
If someone need more information I am able to add more code and explain better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer it is this.
I found through debugging.
It needed to be two way data binding.

```
<select #selectedValue name="selectedValue"
        id="selectedValue" [(ngModel)]="data.career.employmentType" //here
         class="col-md-12 form-control-sm">
           <option *ngFor="let employment of employmentType"
                   [ngValue]="employment" [selected]="employment">
                {{employment.description | translate}}
           </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can update your html `options`.

and your options of html to be

```
<option *ngFor="let employment of employmentType" [ngValue]="employment.name" [selected]="employment">
   {{employment.description | translate}}
</option>
```

Comment: But the enum has the ID, then in this case what are saying the enum it does not make any sense ?

Comment: You are using that enum to display the name in that `select` element. Is it right?

Comment: The enum it is only declared becaus it can be it will be used in different pages.
The name it is the ID but I have writed name.
for example is so defined.
`export enum EmploymentType { EmployedFulltime, EmployedPartTime, }`

Comment: can you add your enum in that question?

Comment: Yes I can add, please see for changes.

Comment: Nope it is a Object which contains the name and the description.

Comment: can you add log value of your `selectedValue`

Comment: Maybe it will be better if I don't use the enum ?
The `selectedValue` is added. see question.
Sorry my bad the console.log of selectedValue it is returning me back only the number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221631/discussion-between-abedin-zhuniqi-and-arunkumar-ramasamy).